# Conditional content in metadata drop down

Tags: managed-metadata

When adding a document, I would like the choices for a column/field to appear in a drop down list depending on what the user chooses in a different column.  So, if Column/field B has 30 items to select, only a part of those items will appear depending on what the user soelected in Column/field A.

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is for a cascading dropdown in a SharePoint Form. You can do this using jQuery to simplify calls to SharePoint web services.

Marc Anderson has a blog series where he does this: http://sympmarc.com/2009/07/14/cascading-columns-in-a-sharepoint-form/